# Checkbox de datagrid en C# se marcan y desmarcan solos

Tags: c#, c++, datagrid, xaml

Tengo un programa que envía a correos en c# con la vista en xaml. El programa hace una select a una base de datos y llena un datagrid que es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aproximadamente me carga mas de 1000 registros y pasa que al seleccionar algunos en específicos se desmarquen otros solos o se marquen algunos diferentes.
Estuve seleccionando unos al azar al principio,  pero si selecciono también algunos de los últimos
resultados y vuelvo a subir, los checkbox ya están deseleccionados, los vuelvo a seleccionar y si nuevamente vuelvo a bajar, encuentro algunos checkbox que se han desmarcado y otros registros se marcaron solos.

Supongamos que al principio del datagrid selecciono los registros 0, 10 y 610.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bajo por la mitad del data grid y selecciono otros 3 registros (17984, 18812 y 18522)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y por ultimo selecciono algunos del final del datagrid (el 23291 y el 23300)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Ahora, si vuelvo a subir al principio del data grid me encuetro con que se desmarco el 620 y se marcaron los primeros 2.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].
Si bajo a la mitad, se desmarco el 18522
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y en la ultima parte se marco el 23295.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del datagrid es este.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NominaGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="261,201,23,152" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">


    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding isCheck}">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" Checked="chkSelectAll_Checked" Unchecked="chkSelectAll_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox  Name="chkSelectAll" Checked="chkSelectAll_Checked" Unchecked="chkSelectAll_Unchecked"/>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding isCheck}"  Unchecked="chkSelect_Unchecked" Checked="chkSelect_Checked"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Empleado" Binding="{Binding nEmpleado}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Nombre}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding email}"  IsReadOnly="True" Width="450" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Pienso que es por la cantidad de registros, el uso de la ram es algo excesivo y un mismo click afecta a diferentes checkbox... No se

Alguna idea de como resolver esto?. Saludos

Comment: si, fijate que hace que en el codigo haga que pase eso... no es ni RAM, ni cantidad de registros.. salvo que este mal el control, debe ser otra cosa.. pero nadie va a poder ayudarte salvo que armes un escenario donde sepamos que pasa.. inclusive capaz que tenes un evento que lo hace...

Comment: Ya agregue mas detalle de los sucedido.

Comment: eso no es detalle.. detalle es el codigo de los eventos por ejemplo... eso que pusiste es un ejemplo que no ayuda a ayudarte...

Comment: Como mínimo pasa la clase que usas binding, el evento check i el uncheck. Para que podamos replicar el error